# VBA - SumIfs with Or

Tags: vba, excel

I have researched this issue everywhere, and I can't find an answer to my particular situation.

Here's my SumIfs statement.

```
B_white = Application.SumIfs(Range("G84:G" & LastRow), Range("G84:G" & LastRow), "1", Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", Range("L84:L" & LastRow), "2 (test)")
```

For the final criterion, it needs to look for "2 (test)" OR just "2" but I can't use "2*" because there will be cells with "22" and "28" in them.

How can I alter this SumIfs statement so that it looks for "2 (test)" or "2"?

Comment: `SUM(SUMIFS(....,....,......, ,{"2","2 (test)"}))` there is no inbuilt OR support for `SUMIFS`, just pass the criteria in an array and sum their results.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the statement.

Comment: @cyboashu `{` is not a valid character in vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner yes. So you can use `Array` in VBA. `x = Application.Sum(Application.SumIfs(Range("a1:a10"), Range("b1:b10"), Array("2", "2 (test)")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B_white = Application.Sum(Application.SumIfs(Range("G84:G" & LastRow), Range("G84:G" & LastRow), "1", Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", Range("L84:L" & LastRow), Array("2 (test)", "2")))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Sumproduct` with an *array-version* of `SumIfs`:

```
B_white = Application.SumProduct(Application.SumIfs(Range("G84:G" & LastRow), _
    Range("G84:G" & LastRow), "1", Range("K84:K" & LastRow), "B*", _
    Range("L84:L" & LastRow), Array("2", "2 (test)")))

'                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```