# How to use OR Operator with SumIfs()

Tags: vba, excel

How do I use SumIfs to sum if 1 out of 3 criteria (=OR) matches?

How can I use OR for the criteria? Here is the pseudocode.

```
Sub SumDemo()

    Dim Sum

    Sum = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs([REVENUE], [UNIT], "=avengers", [region], "=north OR =south OR = west")

    MsgBox Sum

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try googling “VBA excel sumifs Or” and you will find result #1:

[VBA - SumIfs with Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931598/vba-sumifs-with-or)

```
Dim Sum as Double
Dim Revenue As Range, Unit As Range, Region As Range

'You will need to define your ranges.
Set Revenue = Range("")
Set Unit ...
Set Region ...

Sum = Application.Sum(Application.SumIfs(Revenue, Regions, Unit, "Avengers", Array("North", "south","west")))
```

Comment: this should be a comment. Not an answer exactly. You might get down votes for this. :)

Comment: @cyboashu I know I might (oops), but it does answer the question.

Comment: yep... agreed .

Comment: @cyboashu I always forget that one must use late binding to make this work.

Comment: @Sercho as you are correct that duplicate answers the question, please provide how to use that in this instance.  Link only answers, especially ones that point to a duplicate here, are usually down voted.  If you keep the link and show how to use it in this specific instance then it becomes an answer, that no one should down vote.

Comment: @ScottCraner understood, will amend.

Comment: Is it possible to use SumIfs and Range within an UDF without passing the RANGE as function parameter?

Comment: @fabian that would be a whole other question. You should post it separately and see what people think

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach than the duplicate, Use Evaluate to evaluate the worksheet formula.

```
Dim Sm As Long

Sm = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("Sum(SumIfs(REVENUE, UNIT, ""avengers"", region, {""north"", ""south"", ""west""}))")

MsgBox Sm
```

Comment: Why double "" // never seen this before?!

Comment: Because it is inside the first and last `"`.  It needs to be doubled to actually retain the one.  If not vba thinks the string ends.

Comment: How do I actually use that answer without ActiveSheet.Evaluate?! The MsgBox shows the formula. Not the sum.

Comment: You have to use the evaluate with my answer, otherwise you need to use the method on the duplicate.

Comment: Is it also possible to use SumIfs and Range within an UDF without passing the RANGE as function parameter? – fabian 2 mins ago   edit