# CountIfs with multiple criteria as array

Tags: vba, excel

Any idea how to use an array instead of a super-long CountIfs Statement?

Pseudocode:

```
CountProjects = Application.CountIfs(revenueRange, ">0", revenueRange, "<10000", commitmentRange, Array("chance", "save", "canceled"))
```

Comment: just like you would with your question on SUMIFS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982724/how-to-use-or-operator-with-sumifs

Comment: Thanks. I always got an error when using array in CountIfs. But Sum() actually solved it. Debugging/Loggin in VBA is still a pain for me.