# WorksheetFunction.CountIfs VBA, that uses an Array

Tags: arrays, vba, worksheet-function

Looking to use an Array within a countif.

Example

```
Sheets("Data").Select
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
UserArray = Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4")

Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), "16-*", Range("B:B"), "Z*", Range("S:S"), UserArray(), Range("AQ:AQ"), "")
```

As is this will not execute line Z = countifs,etc,etc....

How/Can you define an array within a countifs what would the syntax be?

Thanks,

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982724/how-to-use-or-operator-with-sumifs  but instead of SUMIFS you would do the COUNTIFS the same way.

Comment: @ScottCraner So the array works like OR? I see that the second arg is variant.

Comment: Yes, So the array works like an or. Thanks!

Comment: @QHarr yes, if on the worksheet `=SUM(COUNTIF(A:A,{"Foo","Bar"})` this would count every cell in column A that is either `Foo` or `Bar`.

Comment: Reviewing the link Scott provided, it looks like I am to use something like    Application.Sum(Application.Countifs((Range("A:A"), "16-*", UserArray())))  However, this does not work, it seems like putting the whole array in there like the example works, however that is very messy. Is there a way to simply reference it within?

Comment: To maybe clarify....     
This does not work............Application.Sum(Application.Countifs((Range("A:A"), "16-*", UserArray())))..........This does......................Application.Sum(Application.Countifs((Range("A:A"), "16-*", Array("Name1", "Name2")))