# VBA using SUMIFS with more criteria

Tags: vba, criteria, sumifs

I have a problem with using the SUMIFS in VBA. The thing is I need to use SUMIFS to sum 1+ cities in my dataset.

I have tried to google and use STackoverflow and found 2 anwers where I tried both, but none of them workd. One of them was:

[VBA - SumIfs with Or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931598/vba-sumifs-with-or)

```
Dim D As Double

D = WorksheetFunction.Sum(WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("D2:D2000"), _
Range("A2:A2000"), Array("Århus", "København")))
MsgBox D
```

I expect a numeriacal result, but I get the result "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These will need to be late bound so use `Application.` instead of `WorksheetFormula`:

As per [@MathieuGuindon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998910/vba-using-sumifs-with-more-criteria/57998995?noredirect=1#comment102404837_57998995):

> The result should be captured into a Variant to prevent a type mismatch upon assignment of D if any of the values involved is a worksheet error.

```
Dim D As Variant

D = Application.Sum(Application.SumIfs(Range("D2:D2000"), _
Range("A2:A2000"), Array("Århus", "København")))
If IsNumeric(D) Then MsgBox D
```

Comment: The result should be captured into a `Variant` to prevent a *type mismatch* upon assignment of `D` if any of the values involved is a worksheet error.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon added.